# My UIStackView Frames is getting stacked on each other

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, xcode8

i have created a UIStackview file that set up some frames with Stackview. in those frames i have defined 2 levels with each its StackView frame view

```
    class Stages: UIStackView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    SetupImages()
    SetUpStageOne()
    if scorenum == 1 {
        SetupImages()
        SetUpStageTwo()
    }
}

required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    SetupImages()
    SetUpStageOne()
    if scorenum == 1 {
        SetupImages()
        SetUpStageTwo()
    }

}
```

}

if the score is equal to == 1
i want the frame of SetUpStageTwo() to update

the problem however is that the frame of SetUpStageOne() is getting stacked up on top ofSetUpStageOne()

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution for this question. turns out i needed to delete my arrays before reuse them again by

removefromsuperview(array)

if anyone have a better idea or some improvement to the code above, please post ahead